# Process a lot of requests with aiohttp from a file

Tags: python, multithreading, url, asynchronous, http-post

I'm really new to python in general. I know a little from everything and I've decided to try to process data with POST automatically in an async way.
Found out about aiohttp and everything turns fine, the POST request is done asynchronous and checking on the server I get the inputs.

My problem is when I try with a file larger, with 300.000 lines, each line containing a post request ( actually there's a file with 50.000 lines and an another one with 6, containing something like data1=datafromfile1&data2=datafromfile2).

I've tried using a Thread with a Queue to read from the files and meanwhile to post the requests but it didn't work for me. Here's my code anyway:

```
import random
import asyncio
import re
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import queue

headers = [ "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
]


port = input("Port: ")
thread = input("Thread: ")

async def fetch(url,data1,data2):
    url = "https://" + url + ":%s"%str(port)+"/?&d1="+data1 +"&d2=" + data3 + "&data3=testing"
    header = { "User:Agent" : random.choice(headers)}
    async with ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)) as session:
            try:
                #with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
                async with session.post(url,headers=header) as response:
                    test = response.status
                    if test == 200:
                        print ("POSTED")
                    else:
                        print ("WRONG [%d]"%test )
                    return test
            except Exception as e:
                print ("ERROR [%s]"%type(e).__name__  )
                return 0


async def bound_fetch(sem, url,data1,data2):
    # getter function with semaphore
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url,data1,data2)





async def run(tuples):

    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(int(thread))
    for (url,data1,data2) in tuples:
        # pass Semaphore to every GET request
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem,url,data1,data2))
        tasks.append(task)

    responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    await responses
```

this is where I read the data and process it. I'm creating a tuple with the url and posts in case I decide to change my post.php or add more.

Rest of the code:

```
def main():
    global tuples
    with open("data1.txt") as log_file:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            for line in log_file:
                tuples = []
                with open("data2.txt") as data_file:
                    for data2 in data_file:
                        data2 = data2.strip('\n')
                        tuples.append((url,data1,data2))
                future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(tuples))
                #why doesn't it stop after the 
                #first 6(one data from a file, 6 datas from the other)
                #links done?
                loop.run_until_complete(future)
                print ("Done a batch.")
            loop.close()

main()
```

I'm pretty sure I didn't understand something from the documentation on the aiohttp. Is there any function like thread.join like the one from threading in order to stop reading until run_untill_complete finish its job, untill I actually get a response? I didn't quite understand the Future Object.

Also, I get a OSError on Debian Linux, my virtual machine where I test the script, after a while. It says the name or server is unknown, even tho it works, some requests get this. Any suggests? Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone will ever wonder, I got it to work as I intended just by
    connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
to
    connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False,limit = thread)

Comment: I still get that OSError, when it says that the name or service not known, even tho with the other requests to the SAME site are resolved.